# Get the document library folder url in SharePoint designer workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to send notifications when files are uploaded in folders of document library. I needed to sent folder url instead of filenames uploaded to the Document library. I can use both SharePoint 2010 or 2013 workflows.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 2013 workflow and can split the string from document url for folder name.You can eliminate the file name and use the url upto folder name in workflow.